# How can I move my social media icons down using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

**Q1**

Firstly, how can I move down `<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>` and `<a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>` without affecting the content within section 1 so the icons will be inline with the navigation bar text "Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio" using bootstrap?

Here is a picture of how my site currently looks so you can see the current issue at hand.

[image]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tgdmre65/)

```
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-default {
      background-color: #4D5061;
      height: 10vh;
      z-index: 100;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-default ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: right;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-default ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .dropdown-menu li {
      text-align: center
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
      background-color: #4D5061;
    }

    .dropdown .dropdown-menu a {
      color: white;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 14pt;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      right: 50%;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 50%;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      border-radius: 9px;
      transition: all .2s;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-default ul li a:hover {
      color: white;
      background-color: rgba(20, 50, 40, 0.5)
    }

    .nav.navbar-nav,
    .nav.navbar-nav>li {
      float: none;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-default ul li:hover:after {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    .nav-title {
      font-size: 14pt;
      margin: 0;
      top: 35px;
      left: 50px;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li,
    .navbar.navbar-default ul.dropdown-menu li a {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }

    #logo {
      padding-top: 2vh;
      padding-left: 20px;
      float: left;
    }

    .hero {
      background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/48727/pexels-photo-48727.jpeg") center center no-repeat;;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      position: relative;
      background-size: cover;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100%;
    }

    section {
      position: relative;
      padding:10vh 0 0;
      min-height:100vh;
    }

    .section1 {
      height: 100vh;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .section2 {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
      min-height:90vh;
    }

    .fa-angle-down {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }

    .fa-angle-up {
      color: #4D5061;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0px;
    }

    .icon-style {
   position: relative;
   top:20px;
    }   

    .footer {
      height: 3vh;
      background-color: #4D5061;
      padding: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }

    .footertext {
      font-size: 14pt;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .profile.box {
      bottom: 0;
      height: 50%;
      left: 0;
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 50%;
    }

    .shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      display: inline-block;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 250px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 250px;
    }

    .shape2 {
      background: linear-gradient(35deg, #4D5061, #4D5061);
      border-radius: 85px;
      color: white;
      height: 40px;
      margin: 1% auto;
      opacity: 0.9;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0px;
      width: 250px;
    }

    .fa {
      padding: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      margin: 7px 6px;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .fa:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
    } 

    .fa-twitter {
      background: #55ACEE;
      color: white;
    }

    .fa-linkedin {
      background: #007bb5;
      color: white;
    }

    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);

    #feedback-page{
      text-align:center;
    }

    #form-main{
      width:100%;
      float:left;
      padding-top:0px;
    }

    #form-div {
      background-color:rgba(72,72,72,0.4);
      padding-left:35px;
      padding-right:35px;
      padding-top:35px;
      padding-bottom:50px;
      width: 850px;
      height: 500px;
      float: left;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-top:30px;
      margin-left: -260px;
      -moz-border-radius: 7px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    }
    .feedback-input {
      color:#3c3c3c;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight:500;
      font-size: 18px;
      border-radius: 0;
      line-height: 22px;
      background-color: #fbfbfb;
      padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      width:100%;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 3px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    }

    .feedback-input:focus {
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 0;
      border: 3px solid #3498db;
      color: #3498db;
      outline: none;
      padding: 13px 13px 13px 54px;
    }

    .focused{
      color:#30aed6;
      border:#30aed6 solid 3px;
    } 

    #name {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #name:focus {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/name.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 8px 5px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #email {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }


    #email:focus {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/email.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #comment {
      background-image: url(http://rexkirby.com/kirbyandson/images/comment.svg);
      background-size: 30px 30px;
      background-position: 11px 8px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      line-height: 150%;
      resize:vertical;
    }


    input:hover, textarea:hover,
    input:focus, textarea:focus {
      background-color:white;
    }


    #button-blue {

      font-family: 'Montserrat', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      float:left;
      width: 100%;
      border: #fbfbfb solid 4px;
      cursor:pointer;
      background-color: #3498db;
      color:white;
      font-size:24px;
      padding-top:22px;
      padding-bottom:22px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
      transition: all 0.3s;
      margin-top:-4px;
      font-weight:700;
    }

    #button-blue:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
      color: #0493bd;
    }

    .submit:hover {
      color: #3498db;
    }

    .ease {
      width: 0px;
      height: 74px;
      background-color: #fbfbfb;
      -webkit-transition: .3s ease;
      -moz-transition: .3s ease;
      -o-transition: .3s ease;
      -ms-transition: .3s ease;
      transition: .3s ease;
    }  

    .submit:hover .ease {
      width:100%;
      background-color:white;
    } 

    @media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
    #form-div {
      left: 3%;
      margin-right: 3%;
      width: 88%;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 3%;
      padding-right: 3%;
    }
  </style>

</head>
```

```
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
        <h1 class="nav-title">Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</h1>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">About Me <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#section3">Contact</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Units <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>


  <section id="section1" class="section1">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="profile box">
        <div class="shape"></div>
        <div class="shape2">
          <p>kjjjjjjjjjkjjjkkjkj</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>





    <a href="#contact-me"> <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>
  <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section section2">

      <h2 class="contact-text">Contact Me Now!</h2>
      <div id="form-main">
          <div id="form-div">
              <form class="form" id="form1">
                  <p class="name">
                      <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                  </p>
                  <p class="email">
                      <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                  </p>
                  <p class="text">
                      <textarea name="text" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                  </p>
                  <div class="submit">
                      <input type="submit" value="SEND" id="button-blue"/>
                      <div class="ease"></div>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>

    <a href="#section1"> <i class="fa fa-angle-up" style="font-size:100px;"></i></a>

  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js" integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <footer>
    <div class="footer">
      <h2 class="footertext">Copyright © 2017 Liam Docherty's Site. All rights reserved.</h2>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you've left out a bit-o-css. The screen shot doesn't match the JSFiddle or Stack Snippet.

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Still doesn't replicate your screenshot.

Comment: It does, just changed the view after you input the code to 80%

Comment: You forgot to include Bootstrap's CSS with your code. Typically a question should contain a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We have to go out and find additional resources that were not included with your code to replicate your screenshot. We shouldn't have to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The fiddle is not displaying properly so its tough to say, but try the following CSS to the .fa elements:

```
position: relative;
top: 10px;
```

adjust top to whatever works

Comment: Updated the post. Apologies there was an error in the initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add this to your css. You can adjust margin-top according to your needs, this should work since you got simple links.

```
.navbar-header a.fa-twitter, .navbar-header a.fa-linkedin {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-top:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter icon-style"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin icon-style"></a>
```

CSS

```
.icon-style {
   position: relative;
   top:20px;
}
```

Comment: Updated the post.

Comment: Using bootstrap how can I do this? Your code doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I noticed that you have included the `.icon-style` in CSS code of your questions, but, you have included the `class` in `a` tags too, just like this: `class="fa fa-twitter icon-style"`. Try this and let me know if it work!